# Find elements in one column of a vector that aren't in another column

Tags: c++, vector

The main purpose of this snippet is I needed a way to find all of the elements that exist in one column of a vector but not another, and then the next, and so on.

I have a vector whose contents will always be presorted and will always be unique strings (on a per-column basis) by nature of the files in which they were populated from.

The size variables, rowa (rows) and fnamec (columns) are calculated at run-time.
Each column represents data that's been imported from a file. Column 0 = file 1, column 1 = file 2, etc.
The number of files vary as does the number of rows each contains.
As the files are being processed I store the number of rows in each in an array to reference so I'm not hitting the empty rows.

My array is set up thusly with test data of how I would have it populated:

```c
    std::vector<std::vector<string> > array(rowa, std::vector<string>(fnamec));

[0,0]apple   [0,1]apple [0,2]banana
[1,0]banana  [1,1]banana[1,2]bean
[2,0]cucumber[2,1]bean  [2,2]grape
[3,0]grape   [3,1]carrot[3,2]pear
[4,0]        [4,1]grape [4,2]tomato
[5,0]        [5,1]pear  [5,2]
[6,0]        [6,1]tomato[6,2]
[7,0]        [7,1]      [7,2]
```

With the example data, execution returns:

```
cucumber not in next column

apple not in next column
carrot not in next column
```

(As it would compare column 1 to column 2 and column 2 to column 3, etc.)

```c
    int ksrow = 0;                                          // Source row                                                                             
    int kscol = 0;                                          // Source column. We start at [0,0]        
    int ktrow = 0;                                          // Target row
    int ktcol = 1;                                          // Target column. We start at [0,1]
    int colmatch = 0;                                       // Set match(?) initially to no

for(int kloop = 0; kloop < fnamec-1; ++kloop)               // Check all columns against next...
    {
    int ksqty = rarray[kscol][0];                           // rarray is where row sizes are stored
    int ktqty = rarray[ktcol][0];                           

    for(int kcol = 0; kcol < ksqty; ++kcol)                 // Check all individual names from A in all of B...
        {
        for(int krow = 0; krow < ktqty; ++krow)             // Check if individual name exists in all of B
            {
            if(array[ksrow][kscol] == array[krow][ktcol])   // Check if a column matches
                {
                colmatch = 1;                               // Set match flag to true   
                }
            }
            if (colmatch == 0)                              // If match not true then...
                {
  cout << array[ksrow][kscol] << " not in next column" << endl;    // ...display unmatched entry
                }
        colmatch = 0;                                       // Reset match flag
        ksrow++;                                            // Increment source row
        }
        cout << "\n" << endl;                               // Add newline to display to separate list views
    ksrow = 0;                                              // Reset source row
    kscol++;                                                // Increment source column
    ktrow = 0;                                              // Reset target row
    ktcol++;                                                // Increment target column
    }
```

As is, the code seemingly works as it should, I'm just not sure that what I came up with is the most efficient way of going about it, especially if/when it's applied to larger datasets.
(Which is why I also mentioned how I set the data up in case that factors into a better solution).

My next step will be to also have it display the opposite as well, elements that have been added as opposed to dropped but figured I'd nip this in the bud first before I potentially make more work for myself if an overhaul is necessary.

Comment: [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)